# Bower jQuery not working Silex

Tags: jquery, bower, silex

Hi i am working on a app in Silex. I installed bower to download jQuery and other libraries. When i include jQuery in twig i get a error that $ is not defined but jQuery is imported the right way.

Here is my twig include code

```
<srcipt src="{{ global.request.basepath }}/components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></srcipt>
<script src="{{ global.request.basepath }}/js/app.js"></script>
```

app.js is working fine

Here is a picture of my web folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

I get no errors that jQuery is not found but for some reason it is not working.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to use jQuery before it's ready. Have you written jQuery already that isn't working?

Comment: my app.js is looking like this $(function() {
    //Button
    var element, circle, d, x, y;
    $(".askButon span").click(function(e){});

Comment: with }); ad the end ;)

Comment: What's the value of `global.request.basepath`?

Comment: the value is string(0) ""

Comment: the problem is fixed i think it was a hidden character on the line where i imported jquery. I included it on a new line and removed the old one now it is working fine thank you for your help :)